# How can I store values which are clicked into an array & output a response?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am creating a tarot card reading game in which the user is to click 6 cards and those cards will each have a meaning to them. I want the meaning to be displayed in a new page once all 6 cards of their choice have been clicked.

I need help finding a way to take the chosen cards & store the them and then link each card to a meaning.

I am thinking that maybe it is possible to store the chosen cards into an array then take the array and match it up with a description, but I dont know how to implement this in JavaScript.

I have provided a codepen of what I currently have:
https://codepen.io/cramos2/pen/oKEBPQ

I have tried adding an "onclick" event listener to each card div & linking it to a function which matches it to the class name but this does not work and breaks the code.

```
<div class="card">
      <div class="card-back card-face card1" onclick=summary()>
       1
      </div>
      <div class="card-front card-face">
        The Hermit
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
function summary(){

  if(document.getElementByClassName('card1'){
     alert("card 1 has been clicked");
     }
}
```

I expect for it to be recognized which card was chosen & for me to able to write corresponding text for the card

Comment: `if (document.getElementByClassName('card1'))` you're missing a closing parenthesis there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function summary(e){
  if(e.classList.contains("card1")) {
    alert("card 1 has been clicked")
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
      <div class="card-back card-face card1" onclick="summary(this)">
       1
      </div>
      <div class="card-back card-face card2" onclick="summary(this)">
       2
      </div>
      <div class="card-front card-face">
        The Hermit
      </div>
    </div>
```

> Explanation

`onclick="summary(this)"` in the html will pass current element to the function summary

```
if(e.classList.contains("card1")) {
    alert("card 1 has been clicked")
  }
```

will determine whether the element has `card1` in the class list... if it does, pop up an alert window

Answer (score 0):

As the comment correctly suggests, your current code doesn't work because there's a missing parenthesis, it should be:

```
if ( doThing() )
```

Instead of

```
if ( doThing()
```

Regarding the "how", the easiest way I see would be to add a `data-meaning` [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

This way you could just:

1. Attach corresponding attribute to each html-object that represents a card.
2. Attach an event listener to all of them that would call a callback passing an [event element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) once card is clicked.

It'd look something like:

```
document.addEventListener(
   `click`,
   doThing
);
```

3. Our abstract `doThing` would actually need to do *two* things.

More precisely it'd need to

1. Extract `data-meaning` value from each object clicked (it might be done with event object mentioned above).
2. Somehow keep track of how many times different cards were clicked,
   for example, [pushing](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) meanings into an array & checking array length.

Hope this helps!